# What is the difference in string.Equals("string") and "String".Equals(string)?

Tags: c#

Is there any difference in following two lines of code that compares the string values.

```
string str = "abc";

if(str.Equals("abc"))
```

and

```
if("abc".Equals(str))
```

in the first line I am calling the equals method on string variable to compare it with string literal. The second line is vice versa. Is it just the difference of coding style or there is a difference in the way these two statements are processed by the compiler.

Comment: Side note: `"abc".Equals(str)` is nicknamed a "Yoda Condition".

Comment: @Jerord, +1 for telling the name of the condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the way the compiler processed the statements is different. The function equals for String in most languages follows the same guidlines. Here is a semicode:

```
override def Equals(that:String):Boolean //Should override Object.Equals
  if(that==null) return false
  for i from 0 to this.length
    if(!this(i).Equals(that(i))) return false
  return true
```

Normally, the method will fisrt check that *that* IS a String, and that *this* and *that* have the same length.

You can see, as others pointed out, that if *that* is `null` the method returns *false*. On the other hand, the method is part of of String so it cannot be called on `null`. That is why in your exampleif str is null you will get a `NullReferenceException`.

That being said, if you know both variables are non-null Strings of the same length, both statements will evaluate to the same in the same time.

Answer (score 30):

The only difference is that, in the first case, when you do:

```
str.Equals("abc")
```

If `str` is `null`, you'll get an exception at runtime.  By doing:

```
"abc".Equals(str)
```

If `str` is `null`, you'll get `false`.

Answer (score 10):

The difference is that in the second example, you will never get a `NullReferenceException` because a literal can't be null.

Comment: But `((string)null).Equals(str)` ! (Just kidding.)

Answer (score 7):

To add to the other answers: the static `string.Equals("abc", str)` method always avoids triggering a null reference exception, regardless of which order you pass the two strings.

Answer (score 4):

As mmyers said, you the second example will not throw a `NullReferenceException` and while allowing the program to "appear" to run error free, may lead to unintended results.